# cp --archive / -a in Ruby

Tags: ruby, copy

Ruby have FileUtils with `cp`, `cp_r`, having options like `verbose`, `noop` etc. Is there any way to do `cp -a` in a clean way like that? I want to preserve attributes, especially dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using it with the `preserve` option set:

```
FileUtils.cp_r(source, dest, preserve: true)
```